# Create / launch preact project from Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, preact

I have a Visual Studio with several projects inside of it (APIs, etc).

I want to add a Preact project to this solution, so I'm available to launch all of them at the same time.

How can I make a Preact project using Visual Studio 2022?
I can generate a React project, but is it possible to do the same for a Preact one?

If so, how do I have to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio has no menu item for creating a Preact project, no. You can create one using whatever tools you'd like ([`preact-cli`](https://github.com/preactjs/preact-cli) or [`wmr`](https://github.com/preactjs/wmr) are potential first-party options, but you're free to use whatever you'd like) and then you can add the run/build configurations to your IDE, same as any Node script.

Comment: And what should be the template of the project in Visual Studio? Which type of Node? Or just placing the project folder inside the solution is enough?

Comment: That depends entirely on how you want to build your Preact project. Do you want to use an existing build tool that comes with a way to scaffold your projects? Then use it, and place the new project in your existing solution/project. If you want to build a custom setup for your new Preact project, then yes, the Node template from Visual Studio would be fine.